# How to change anchor color when you hover over a list

Tags: css, hover

I have a following HTML and CSS.

When I hover over a list, I want to change the background color and font color.
However my style does not change when I hover over padding of list, on the border or near a border inside the list.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hbf9D/1/

How can I do it?

```
#nav li{
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#1A365B;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
    padding: 2px 11px 4px 11px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#nav li:hover{
    background-color:#E0F1EA;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0 9px 2px 9px;
}

#nav li a:hover{
    color: #000000;
}

#nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'CantarellBold', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 12px;
}

<ul id="nav" class="grid_16">
    <li><a href="#">FORSIDE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MOBIL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PC OG SERVERE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TJENESTER</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the question (drunk), but this works in Firefox 3.6 Mac.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try following:

```
#nav li:hover a{
    color: #000000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zainshaikh/Hbf9D/3/

Answer (score 0):

it could seem strange, but try to place #nav li a:hover style before #nav li a

Comment: what browser do you test? your code seems work fine in opera, ie, chrome